# Tkinter - Keyword arguement repeated

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

Tried searching around for this error, Currently making a resolution window before my friends program (Helping out with minor stuff) Currently have a problem with trying to use two commands in one line (Probably a easy fix knowing me), if anyone could help me out that would be epic!

Here's the code!

```
res1 = tkinter.Button(settings, text="800x600", fg="ghost white" , bg="grey10", font=(16), command=resolution1, command=close_window)
res2 = tkinter.Button(settings, text="1024x768", fg="ghost white" , bg="grey10", font=(16), command=resolution2, command=close_window)
res3 = tkinter.Button(settings, text="1280x720", fg="ghost white" , bg="grey10", font=(16), command=resolution3, command=close_window)
res4 = tkinter.Button(settings, text="1920x1080", fg="ghost white" , bg="grey10", font=(16), command=resolution4, command=close_window)
```

If you need the full code just shout!

Many thanks!

Comment: It's complaining about your assigning the command attribute twice. If you want the command to do multiple things, you need to call a function and have the function do the multiple things.

Comment: Cheers! Realised this! thank you, Had a one line function, so yeah my bad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to use commands with buttons is to have a button call a function. In that function you can do whatever you want, including calling multiple functions:

```
def do_resolution1():
    resolution1()
    close_window()

def do_resolution2():
    resolution2()
    close_widnow()
...
res1 = tkinter.Button(..., command=do_resolution1)
res2 = tkinter.Button(..., command=do_resolution2)
```

You could also write a single function that takes another function as an argument, runs it, and then calls `close_window`. You can then use `lambda` to call that function with different arguments for each button:

I don't recommend this approach for beginners because `lambda` can be confusing.

```
def set_resolution(func):
    func()
    close_window()
...
res1 = tkinter.Button(..., command=lambda: set_resolution(resolution1))
res2 = tkinter.Button(..., command=lambda: set_resolution(resolution2))
...
```

Comment: Yeah as Ron pointed out I could of added the close window command to my function, Thank you though! Knew it was a stupid error, to be honest its my first day of programing tkinter and should of used common sense aha